# configuration to disable "Retype new password" in RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, passwd

Is there a configuration setting in RHEL/CentOS thru which "Retype new password" can be disabled while changing user password.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.  Try the Unix & Linux community.

Comment: What program are you running to change your password?  chpasswd?

Comment: Apologies for posting in the incorrect community.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck!